# copy all the nsdata bytes into a char* error

Tags: c++, ios, c, nsdata, pjsip

I have the following situation:

```
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentOfFile:[fileURL path] options:0 error:nil];
```

I need to send this audioData to the server using a method that accepts as input parameter `pj_str_t value;`

So I did:

```
unsigned char *getBytes = (unsigned char*)[audioData bytes]; //here insteand of 10600 bytes I only have 4 bytes.
value=pj_str((char*)getBytes);
```

The value is a string from 4 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not going to want to pretend a raw piece of binary data is a string. Try encoding it into base64 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that audio data can contain 0's and the pj_str(char *) function you're using will mistake them for the end of the string. Try this:

```
pj_str_t string;
pj_strset(&string, getBytes, [audioData length]);
```

Comment: I need to use the method pjsua_im_send(...) in order to send a file to a destination through the server. With simple text message things do work great. I use: const char* message= [NSStringValue UTF8String]; pj_str_t value= ((char*)message); That s all. Why..with nsdata...things do seem so hard?

Comment: also i read that using udp i can only send a payload of max 60K. also if audioData is bigger than 60k how could i split the buffer in 2 smaller buffers and than call pjsua_im_send methiod twice.

Comment: how could i make use that if there are 0's the pj_str will read all the bytes till aat the lest one? Using the idea you ve posted will I send all the data to the destination? I ll check this at first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: All I'm replacing from your code is the creation of "value". I don't have enough context or knowledge of the library you're using to help you on this second thing. NSData is not the problem: it works for your other strings because they don't have \0's inside of them. Your audio data might have \0's so you need to prevent them from being considered the end of the string, by passing the length yourself.

Comment: thank you. i ll test it and let you know if it s working in a couple of hours.

Comment: it seems to work. How can I now convert the pj_str_t string to NSData?

Comment: if my [audioData length]>4K and I only want to send 4K once how should i do this? Should i save in an array the &text and for each next 4K add a new element in the array?

Comment: No, you can cap it like this:
pj_strset(&string, getBytes, MIN([audioData length], 4 * 1024));

Comment: and what if i have 60 k to send and i want to send it n 4k packets? can you please help me with this?